# Remove rows with conditions using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'd like to remove rows in my data frame that looks like

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "m", "m", "m", "m", "n", "q"),
                 col2 = c("a", "b", "m", "x", "y", "z", NA, "p"))
  col1 col2
1    a    a
2    a    b
3    m    m
4    m    x
5    m    y
6    m    z
7    n <NA>
8    q    p
```

I'm only focusing on `a` and `m` in `Col1` because those values appear in `Col2`. I would like to remove rows where `Col1` and `Col2` don't have matching values.
**Note**: Given that the provided `df` is just a reproducible example for my huge dataset, specifying individual values like 'a' or 'm' wouldn't be suitable.

My desired outcome

```
  col1 col2
1    a    a
2    m    m
3    n   <NA>
4    q    p
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
df %>%
    filter(col1 == col2 | !col1 %in% intersect(col1, col2))
```

which gives

```
  col1 col2
1    a    a
2    m    m
3    n <NA>
4    q    p
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it without specifying `a` and `m` values?

Comment: @Anh then you can use `intersect`, see my update

Comment: Thanks alot. Now I know another function that I never used before.

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding Can you explain abit why you decided to use `intersect` function? the first part `col1 == col2` filters `a` and `m` in two collumn first ( probably excluded other cases), the second part looks for unmatched names (`q` and `p`). But why it ignored `m` and `y` and so on?

Comment: @Anh Here are two conditions 1) the first part is to check if two values are rowwisely equal 2) the second part is to identify the values in `col1` that do not appear in `col2`. Since `y` is not in the intersection of `col1` and `col2` values, so it is omitted.

Comment: So, the key point here is that `y` is omitted because it is associated with `m`, which in another row is connected to itself, right? :)))

Comment: @Anh no, it is omitted because it doesn't appear in both columns, if I understand your request in the question correctly.

Comment: oh yes, sorry. Just simple as that. I don't know why I was obsessed with the connection between values among rows and connecting them to columns.Anyhow, thank you alot!!!